# extern and the XC8 C compiler

Tags: pic, mplabx, xc8

Perhaps I don't fully understand `extern`. With the XC8 C compiler, it seems like I can get away without using it.

In the file `keypad.c` I have a function `signed char keypadGetPressedKeyLabel(void)`. In the header file `keypad.h` I have:

`signed char keypadGetPressedKeyLabel(void);`

I thought I would have to use `extern`, ie:

`extern signed char keypadGetPressedKeyLabel(void);`

The project builds without `extern`. And it works. Might this due to the fact that `keypad.c` and `keypad.h` are all part of the project? I'm using MPLABX.

Comment: Are any other files using `keypad.h`?

Answer (score 2):

`extern` is not strictly necessary for function prototypes in .h files - whether or not the function is actually used in one or many different .c files in your project.
Whether you have `extern int foo(void);`   or just   `int foo(void);`   in your .h your compiler will read is as a function prototype either way.

Its necessary for global variables though since unlike functions they don't have prototypes.
So if you have an  `int thing;`  in one .c file and you want to use it in another .c file then you'll need an  `extern int thing;`  to tell the compiler that it does exist 'somewhere' in your project.

Comment: Correct.  Also, you can include initialization only on the definition of the variable e.g. int a = 0; it is an error to repeat this again in an external declaration e.g. extern int a = 0;  // error

Answer (score 2):

Functions are **extern by default in C**; that's why it works without the keyword.

Comment: This is really the correct answer, but I think it would also benefit from a brief explanation of what extern actually means.

Comment: Great answers; PICs XC8 compiler uses extern looking for external files, not just as a global declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`extern` is really a sign to the linker, that the symbol is defined in a different object file. As you only seem to have one object file, it doesn't make any difference whether it's there or not.

Answer (score 1):

`extern` is largely obsolete for functions in other CUs in many of the smaller simpler compilers.  If a symbol isn't found locally it will be searched for in other CUs and libraries.  You provide a function prototype, but not the actual function, in the CU where you want to use it.

However, `extern` is required for variables that are shared between CUs.  You can't define a prototype for a variable, so the `extern` keyword in this situation has to be used to create the variable equivalent of a function prototype.